# How to launch another app from the flutter desktop application?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a flutter application that communicates to a server in the same machine. So now I need to start the server with the flutter app automatically. So is there any way to start the server when I start the flutter app and kill the server when I close the flutter app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If is in windows you can use the package Win32 :
https://pub.dev/packages/win32

```
try {
   final verb = 'open'.toNativeUtf16();
   final process = 'app.exe'.toNativeUtf16();
   final params = 'p1'.toNativeUtf16();
   final nullParams = ''.toNativeUtf16();
   ShellExecute(0, verb, process, params, nullParams, SW_SHOW);
   return true;
}catch(_){
   return false;
}
```

For Linux u can use process run:
https://pub.dev/packages/process_run

```
var shell = Shell();

await shell.run('''
 app.sh
''');
```

Comment: I want to start the exact same application (windows.exe) (Flutter-Executable) but the window does not show up. I made sure I have the correct absolute and resolved path (In cmd and powershell it worked flawlessly).

Why does no new window spawn?